# How to define a gulp task that initiates watchify and gulp-stylus?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, stylus, watchify

I am trying to create a composite gulp task which runs 2 separate watch tasks at the same time:

```
gulp.task('watch-css', watchCssTask); // uses gulp-stylus
gulp.task('watch-js', watchJsTask);   // uses watchify (browserify)
```

What is the correct way to achieve the following with gulp?

```
gulp.task('watch', watchCssAndJsTask);
```

For instance, with vanilla npm tasks I would just do this:

```
"scripts": {
    "watch-css": ...
    "watch-js": ...
    "watch": "npm run watch-css && npm run watch-js",
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to work:

```
gulp.task('watch', [ 'watch-css', 'watch-js' ]);
```

Comment: Its the right approach, that way it is separated and each task has its own responsibility without inflicting others, and you can reuse it like you did wherever you want.